# MC Content Builder email template with data relationships

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, content-builder

I would like to be able to send an email with different merge fields (are they called like that in MC?). So far, I've figured out how to merge the fields regarding the data extension from where the email template is feeding but, is there any way to be able to reference other data extensions, maybe through data relationships?

At the moment my template is something like this:

```
Dear %%LastName%%,
We would like to contact you on notice of your article %%Article_Title%%
```

Where `Article_Title` is in a different data extension.

I'm not even sure if this is the correct approach, so I'm open to other ones.

Comment: You'll want to use a `lookup` function.  As long as the data extensions are connected (usually by a subscriber_key) you will be able to display fields from related tables.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprowscs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll look something like this:
`%%[SET @city = Lookup(“ShipAreas”,”City”,”Zip”,Zip)]%%`
Then within the html you can call out your variable like this:
`%%=v(@city)=%%`